# Visual Studio Code: can't edit LEFT-side file during COMPARE

Tags: compare, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I open file-VS-file compare mode via:

- clicking on the file A and then "Select for Compare"
- clicking on the file B and then "Compare A with B"

The problem is that I can edit file B (RIGHT side), but **can't** edit file A (LEFT side).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Edit**: this should be working out of the box in vscode version **1.41.0**

It will show `Unknown configuration setting` but it's working.

```json
"diffEditor.originalEditable": true
```

Comment: I can't find this setting in the latest VSCode (1.30.1). Maybe it's from VSCode for Insiders?

Comment: Are you using GUI settings editor? I suppose since it has a warning as `unknown` in json it won't display in the GUI version. That setting is at least couple of years old.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use GUI settings editor. And there is no such option available. But after I manually (using another text editor) added this line to the "settings.json" it worked! Thanks!

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#edit-left-hand-side-in-diffs for pre-release notes demo.

Answer (score 9):

like mentioned [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4180#issuecomment-429537724).

Open VSCode, open the command palette (on windows it's Ctrl + shift+ P), then type setting and open the `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

Then you will see something like this:

Paste `"diffEditor.originalEditable": true,` inside the `{}`

Example:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to say I don't see this on the linux electron app, although it was announced in the internal update news dialog.
If I add it to the user `settings.json` it will be marked in the editor as an unrecognized option.
If I open `defaultSettings.json` via CTRL+shift+P only four `diffEditor.` options are listed without our wanted `.originalEditable` option.

Comment: I revisted the second news item in update log for 1.41.0 and saw that I misunderstood the feature and even the OP-Question. I thought you could use it with git diffs. In the diff-window of a local file comparsion both sides are indeed editable and differences are updated as you type.