# VS Code :: Cannot edit in read-only editor when Compare Selected

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, compare, diff

I'm using VS Code 1.140.1 on MacOS Catalina and I need to compare two files.

1. I open both files with VS Code
2. I select both
3. I right click on them and I select "Compare Selected"

[image]

The comparison works but when I try to edit while comparing I cannot, VS Code says: "Cannot edit in read-only editor".

[image]

That is a bit frustrating because other IDE like Notepad++ they indeed allow you to edit while comparing and this is very useful as it shows you when the 2 files are the same.

Is there any way around?

Or do you suggest to change VS Code with another IDE?

Comment: Is true, @Mark, this is a duplicate. Should I just delete that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After exhaustive research I found the solution here:

[Visual Studio Code: can't edit LEFT-side file during COMPARE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980217/visual-studio-code-cant-edit-left-side-file-during-compare)

In fact only the LEFT side is not editable, the RIGHT side is alright.

Comment: So as alluded to in your link it is coming in v1.41 See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#edit-left-hand-side-in-diffs It is already in the Insider's Build.

Comment: @Mark, you are right. Thank you

Comment: Life saver answer

Comment: so @Mark is wrong? They rolled back the feature?